# How to call recursion in different way?

Tags: c, recursion

When I run this code, I got an exception like

> Unhandled exception at 0x779C017E (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

How do i fixed it ?? And thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fn(int n) {
if (n == 1)
  return 1;
  return fn(n - 1) + fn(n - 2);
}

int main()
{
 int n, k = 1;
 scanf_s("%d",&n);
 k = fn(n);
 printf("%d", k);
 return 1;

}
```

Comment: What input did you give?

Comment: i gave input 5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to determine which line of the code is getting the error?

Comment: Fwiw, here's your homework warning: If this is intended to generate a fibonacci number, your base-case *may* be wrong even with a proper boolean comparator (which is the real problem; see answers below). The first fibonacci number in modern reference is usually considered `0`. [See here for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Double check with your instruction materials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has condition which will always lead to an infinite loop(Not just for `3`).

Consider entering `5` as input. `5` would break into `4` and `3`. `3` would break into `2` and `1`. `2` would break into `1` and `0`. Now the function which gets the `0` value will go into infinite recursion.

This way, whatever value you input, the value will break down to `0` and eventually would lead to infinite recursion. This should be handled in the condition check.

Your condition check should be

```
if (n <= 1)
   return 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Haris, your  solution has been worked fine for me.

Comment: @JoyAcharya Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Your may enter an infinite recursion if n is lower than 3.
You need to change your condition to check if n<3 return 1

Comment: This is true, but she said the inputs she used were all above 4.

Comment: @Barmar: yes, but eventually they get down to below 1, because `n - 2` can leap-frog the `n == 1` test.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
#include<stdio.h>

   int fn(int n) {
   if (n == 1 || n == 0)
      return 1;
      return fn(n - 1) + fn(n - 2);
   }

int main()
{
  int n, k = 1;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  k = fn(n);
  printf("%d", k);
  return 1;

}
```

Here is a little modification

```
    if (n == 1 || n == 0)
```